# How to find an "input" element using Selenium/Python3

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

I am trying to login into Instagram by using selenium and Python but I cant get find input elements like "uername" and "password". I am using Google Chrome

**HTML**

`<label class="_aa48"><span class="_aa4a">Telefonnummer, Benutzername oder E-Mail-Adresse</span><input aria-label="Telefonnummer, Benutzername oder E-Mail-Adresse" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" class="_aa4b _add6 _ac4d" type="text" value="" name="username"></label>`

I looked a lot of similar posts but I guess selenium got updates and none of the solutions are working in my case.

Following code I tried without success:

**My Code (try 1)**

`enter_username = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")`

**My Code (try 2)**

`enter_username = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._aa48")`

Comment: What is error you are getting. Also update the Question with full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` fields have attribute `name`. Can use `NAME` selector and below are the Xpath and CSS selector for the same.

```
Xpath: 
//input[@name='username']

CSS:
input[name='username']
```

Try with below code. It has worked for me.

```
# imports for Explicit waits

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,'username'))).send_keys("username")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,'password'))).send_keys("password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[type='submit']"))).click()
```